# SELECT COLUMNS WHERE COLUMNS VALUE ARE SAME

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table data.

```
column_1_____column_3_____column_4_____column_5_____column_6_____column_7_____column_8 
   yes         no           yes           yes          yes          no           yes
```

**Here, their is only one datarow**

I want only that columns which has `value = 'yes'`.

For this which query works?

Comment: what if column 3 having no and yes both in two rows that what?

Comment: here, their is only one datarow

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119249/return-variable-number-of-columns-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 2):

SQL is not organized around columns.  It is organized around rows.  You can do what you want with a query like this:

```
select 'column1' as col
from t
where column1 = 'yes'
union all
select 'column2' as col
from t
where column2 = 'yes'
union all
. . .
union all
select 'column8' as col
from t
where column8 = 'yes';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your idea isn't suitable for sql logic. Because you want to know something, before query hasn't work yet.